# Alamofire Chunked Upload - How API knows when its the last chunk?

Tags: rest, alamofire, chunked, alamofire-upload

I have a Golang web server that I have written to handle large file uploads 30GB or more. In a proof of concept using Dropzone.js I can upload files of any size with no issue as long as they are chunked.

The way DropzoneJS.js implemented this is that each chunk has items added the to the header like:

dzchunkindex: 435
dzchunksize: 10000
dztotalchunkcount: 3498274

So I receive a chunk, I create the file (if needed), write the data, and check to see if I'm on the last chunk. Then repeat as needed. Once I see I've written the last chunk I close the file.

It seems like Alamofire supports chunked uploads using its AF.Upload method.

However, how should my server know when the last chunk has been uploaded? I can certainly check this a different way. Just curious what that way should be? Ive combed over the Alamofire docs and can't find much.

I can chunk the file manually and upload it but id rather use Alamofire if possible.

Thanks,
Ed